# Is there a built in way to avoid magic strings with the Entity Framework's Include()?

Tags: .net-4.0, entity-framework-4, maintainability, magic-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework Include() strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102909/entity-framework-include-strongly-typed)

Ok, I've got an entity framework query where I use Include to tell it I want a related object loaded:

`var employees = _entities.Employees.Include("Manager").ToList()`

By using include I avoid generating a query for every single employee's manager record (Instead a friendly JOIN is used in the query and the database is never bothered again).

But the use of a magic string "Manager" is unsettling, especially after coming from the supposedly more primitive, quick and dirty Linq2SQL. From a coding stand point it's like a loaded gun, ready to throw a run time exception that should have been caught at compile time. It also puts a big damper on refactoring.

Are there any built in properties or methods to get around this? For example I see `Manager.EntityKeyPropertyName` as a static string property, but this does not seem to be what I want. I'd rather not manually add a hard coded list of constants somewhere, but it would be better then the naked intellisense blind magic strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not any build-in strong typed version of Include in EF 4 (I think it is in EF Features [CTP4](http://romiller.com/2010/07/14/ef-ctp4-tips-tricks-include-with-lambda/) and CTP5). I'm using [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/matthieu/archive/2008/06/06/entity-framework-include-with-func-next.aspx) and I'm quite happy with it.

Comment: Yep, that does exactly what I need, no extra maintanence added.