# Entity Framework Include() strongly typed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Is there a way to make this strongly typed using the System.Data.Entity.Include method?  In the method below Escalation is a ICollection<>.

```
public IEnumerable<EscalationType> GetAllTypes() {
  Database.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
  return Database.EscalationTypes
    .Include("Escalation")
    .Include("Escalation.Primary")
    .Include("Escalation.Backup")
    .Include("Escalation.Primary.ContactInformation")
    .Include("Escalation.Backup.ContactInformation").ToList();
}
```

Comment: If you have EFv4.1 you don't have to use magic strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247324/ef-code-first-ctp5-using-include-method-with-many-to-many-table/5247423#5247423

Comment: This can also interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This is already available in Entity Framework 4.1.

See here for a reference for how to use the include feature, it also shows how to include multiple levels: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(VS.103).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28VS.103%29.aspx)

The strongly typed `Include()` method is an extension method so you have to remember to declare the `using System.Data.Entity;` statement.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Especially for those of us that are so used to ReSharper suggesting ```using``` statements, that we forget that we need to add one manually from time to time.

Comment: The missing using statement was what got me. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Should there be a reason not to use this extension (or the other way around: can there be a reason to use the `include` with the `string` parameter) ?

Answer (score 7):

Credit goes to [Joe Ferner](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/type-safe_entity_framework_inc.html):

```
public static class ObjectQueryExtensionMethods {
  public static ObjectQuery<T> Include<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> exp) {
    Expression body = exp.Body;
    MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)exp.Body;
    string path = GetIncludePath(memberExpression);
    return query.Include(path);
  }

  private static string GetIncludePath(MemberExpression memberExpression) {
    string path = "";
    if (memberExpression.Expression is MemberExpression) {
      path = GetIncludePath((MemberExpression)memberExpression.Expression) + ".";
    }
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
    return path + propertyInfo.Name;
  }
}
```

```
ctx.Users.Include(u => u.Order.Item)
```

Comment: That logic is already included in System.Data.Entity namespace.  You can use Include with a Expression<Func<TSource,TProperty>>.  Notice above that Escalation is an ICollection<Escalation>.