# Linq to Entities 4.0 ('Include'): In search of an elegant way

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm learning Linq to entities on my own and I have a bit of a question. Take a look at the following method. It returns the latest completed task for every item inside the `List of WorkflowsInProgress` . This method is being called within an other method where i'm using the `fields of TasksInProgress` , but i'm also using properties of `the linked Tasks and WorkflowInProgress`. As you will see I've added the `Include` to the query.

```
    public List<TasksInProgress> GetLatestTaskForWorkflowsInProcess(List<WorkflowInProgress> pWorkflowsInProcess)
    {
        List<TasksInProgress> tasksLst = new List<TasksInProgress>();
        List<Int64> workflowIds = pWorkflowsInProcess.Select(w => w.Id).ToList();
        using (TaskWorkflowEntities myDatacontext = new TaskWorkflowEntities())
        {

            tasksLst = (from taskP in myDatacontext.TasksInProgress.Include("Tasks").Include("WorkflowInProgress")
                        where (taskP.RunningState == (int)WorkflowRunningStates.Completed) &&
                        workflowIds.Contains(taskP.WorkflowInProgressId) &&
                        taskP.Completed == (from sTaskP in myDatacontext.TasksInProgress
                                          where sTaskP.WorkflowInProgressId == taskP.WorkflowInProgressId
                                          group sTaskP by sTaskP.WorkflowInProgressId into gSTaskP
                                          select gSTaskP.Max(g => g.Completed)).FirstOrDefault()
                        select taskP).ToList<TasksInProgress>();
        }

        return tasksLst;
    }
```

**My Question is:**

> 'Is there a more elegant way to include other tables inside a Query?'
>   Because i don't like those hardcoded objectnames just sitting there' (Imagine if the tablename changes...)
>
> Or is there any other way that i can use to include the fields of linked objects/navigational properties?

**Note:** Example of the methode above this one:

```
foreach(TasksInProgress taskInProc in _taskWorkflowS.GetLatestTaskForWorkflowsInProcess(currentWorkflowsInProcess))
{
   //Do something with (int)taskInProc.Tasks.TaskOrder
   //Do something with taskInProc.WorkflowInProgress.WorkflowId
   // ...

   //for Instance
   int i = 0;
   i = _taskWorkflowS.GetAmountOfTasksForWorkflow(taskInProc.WorkflowInProgress.WorkflowId, (int)taskInProc.Tasks.TaskOrder)

   if (i > 0 ) 
   { ... }
}
```

**Update:**
using lambda expression as parameter of the `Include` doesn't appear to be working due to the fact that it only excepts string (see image below):[image]

Comment: Please check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102909/entity-framework-include-strongly-typed#answer-10843340

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: EF 4.0 => This is the latest distributed version within the company.

Comment: Then you have to use the solution that @Alberto proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension method that use a lambda expression instead of a string:

```
public static ObjectQuery<T> Include<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
{
    MemberExpression body = selector.Body as MemberExpression;
    return query.Include(body.Member.Name);

}
```

and use it like:

```
myDatacontext.TasksInProgress.Include(q=>q.Tasks)
                             .Include(q=>q.WorkflowInProgress)
```

I have not tested it, but it should work.

Comment: You do not have to do your own extension method. Use the one built into EF

Comment: This is already built-in in Entity Framework. See @Murdock's answer.

Comment: In the older versions this method is not present.

Comment: You are right. :) Maybe you can add this to you answer?

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Answer before the question was changed to Entity Framework 4.0. This will only work for EF 4.1 and later

You can have

```
.Include(o => o.Tasks)
```

if you add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

at least you are not using strings then and you will get errors if the table changes

Comment: found i on the internet and tried that. But the Include method accepts only a single string as parameter. Not a Lambda expression (even with adding System.Data.Entity). Or is there another namespace required? I will add a screenshot of this to my question.

Comment: @svranken Are you using EF 4.1 or later?

Comment: @svranken Method signature: public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path) where T : class; in QueryableExtensions in System.Data.Entity

Comment: EF 4.0 => This is the latest distributed version within the company. Why are we always so far behind on the latest technologies ....

Comment: @svranken sorry mate then this don't work then I suggest you go with the other answer.

Comment: Thnx for the help! I'll give Alberto's solution a shot.