# Entity Framework Include syntax

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We are using Include  in few of our LINQ queries. However was wondering that the include method overload only shows (string path) as parameter, what if we change the database table name(s) and regenerate the entities then the include part will throw runtime errors. How to catch such issues at compile time?

Example:

```
Material has BusinessUnit. 
So we use repo.Material.Include("BusinessUnit")
```

what if we change BusinessUnit entity name to OrgUnit or something else.

Comment: That feature is already existing in Entity Framework 4.1+. See reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10843340/1504480)

Answer (score 4):

Use like below to avoid using `string` in `Include` method

Add the following reference to your file

```
using System.Data.Entity ;
```

And use

```
Context.BusinessUnits.Load();
```

Or

```
Context.Materials.Include(m => m.BusinessUnit).Where(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use to overload of `Include` that uses a lambda expression, then you need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` namespace. The overload is contained in that namespace. Then you would be able to use

`repo.Material.Include(m => m.BusinessUnit)`

You have to be using Entity Framework 4.1 or later to use utilize this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Use Strong Type here

```
repo.Material.Include(m => m.BusinessUnit)
```

Comment: I am using entity framework 6.0, somehow I am not getting that overload. Am I missing something here? If I hit F12 on include i just see                                     public virtual DbQuery<TResult> Include(string path);                                          Do I need to write overload myself?

Comment: this is available from ef 4.1. Not sure why you are not getting the option. please share your entity schema